# How to use activity indicator view on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, android-activity, indicator

An activity indicator view is useful in many applications.
Any ideas about how to add, activiate and dismiss an activity indicator view on iPhone?

All the methods for this are welcomed here.

Comment: I found [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD), which puts a nice modal indicator up. It was dead easy to implement.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

Create:

```
spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
[spinner setCenter:CGPointMake(kScreenWidth/2.0, kScreenHeight/2.0)]; // I do this because I'm in landscape mode
[self.view addSubview:spinner]; // spinner is not visible until started
```

Start:

```
[spinner startAnimating];
```

Stop:

```
 [spinner stopAnimating];
```

When you're finally done, remove the spinner from the view and release.

Comment: How to automatically make center the spinner?

Comment: [spinner stopAnimating]; does not hide the loading. I can still see the loading animation.

Comment: @AdilMalik set spinner.hidesWhenStopped = YES;

Comment: @JuJoDi the actual problem was that my `Create` spinner code was being called more than once, while the code to hide the spinner was called only once. I had to check if the spinner is already visible and animating, don't run the `Create` spinner code. This fixed my problem.

Comment: How to give custom color for this

Answer (score 10):

Take a look at the open source WordPress application.  They have a very re-usable window they have created for displaying an "activity in progress" type display over top of whatever view your application is currently displaying.

http://iphone.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk

The files you want are:

- WPActivityIndicator.xib
- RoundedRectBlack.png
- WPActivityIndicator.h
- WPActivityIndicator.m

Then to show it use something like:

```
[[WPActivityIndicator sharedActivityIndicator] show];
```

And hide with:

```
[[WPActivityIndicator sharedActivityIndicator] hide];
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for as well. Do note that WPActivityIndicator has been renamed (and refactored) to WPProgressHUD (see http://iphone.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/Classes/WPProgressHUD.h).

Comment: sharedActivityIndicator that class methos method not found in your link.

Answer (score 9):

in regards to:

> Take a look at the open source WordPress application. They have a very re-usable window they have created for displaying an "activity in progress" type display over top of whatever view your application is currently displaying.

note that if you do utilise this code you MUST provide ALL the sourcecode to your own application to any user that requests it. You need to be aware that they may decide to repackage your code and sell it on the store themselves. This is all provided for under the terms of the GNU General Public License (GPL).

If you don't want to be forced into opening your sourcecode then you cannot use anything from the wordpress iphone application including the, referenced activity progress window, without forcing the GPL to apply to your own.

Answer (score 7):

The documentation on this is pretty clear. It's a UIView subclass so you use it like any other view. To start/stop the animation you use

```
[activityIndicator startAnimating];
[activityIndicator stopAnimating];
```

Answer (score 2):

***Using Storyboard-***

**Create-**

- Go to main.storyboard (This can be found in theProject Navigator on the left hand side of your Xcode) and drag and drop the "Activity Indicator View" from the Object Library.

[image: Activity Indicator View from Object Library]

- Go to the header file and create an IBOutlet for the UIActivityIndicatorView-

  ```
   @interface ViewController : UIViewController

       @property (nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicatorView;

   @end
  ```
- Establish the connection from the Outlets to the UIActivityIndicatorView.

**Start:**

Use the following code when you need to start the activity indicator using following code in your implementation file(.m)-

```
 [self.activityIndicatorView startAnimating];
```

**Stop:**

Use the following code when you need to stop the activity indicator using following code in your implementation file(.m)-

```
 [self.activityIndicatorView stopAnimating];
```

Answer (score 1):

i think you should use hidden better.

```
activityIndicator.hidden = YES
```

Answer (score 0):

Activity indicator 2 sec show and go to next page

```
@property(strong,nonatomic)IBOutlet UIActivityIndicator *activityindctr;

-(void)viewDidload { [super viewDidload];[activityindctr startanimating]; [self performSelector:@selector(nextpage) withObject:nil afterDelay:2];}

-(void)nextpage{ [activityindctr stopAnimating]; [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"nextviewcintroller" sender:self];}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (IBAction)toggleSpinner:(id)sender
{
    if (self.spinner.isAnimating)
    {
        [self.spinner stopAnimating];
        ((UIButton *)sender).titleLabel.text = @"Start spinning";
        [self.controlState setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:@"SpinnerAnimatingState"];
    }
    else
    {
        [self.spinner startAnimating];
        ((UIButton *)sender).titleLabel.text = @"Stop spinning";
        [self.controlState setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"SpinnerAnimatingState"];
    }
}
```