# Add UIActivityIndicatorView into UIBarButton

Tags: iphone, button, uinavigationbar, uiactivityindicatorview

How do I add a UIActivityIndicatorView spinner circle into a UIBarButton, so that when a user taps on one of those buttons on the navigation bar, they see a spinner while the loading takes place?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

If you're trying to show the activity wheel in a navigation bar button (e.g. you might have a refresh button on your navbar) - you can create a new `UIBarButtonItem` with a custom view being the `UIActivityIndicatorView`:

**Objective-C**

```
uiBusy = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];
uiBusy.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
[uiBusy startAnimating];
[self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem initWithCustomView:uiBusy];
```

**Swift**

```
let uiBusy = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .White)
uiBusy.hidesWhenStopped = true
uiBusy.startAnimating()
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: uiBusy)
```

This overwrites your `rightBarButtonItem` with the spinning wheel. When you're done, just recreate the `rightBarButtonItem`.

Comment: `[self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem initWithCustomView:uiBusy];` seems dodgy to me. I would expect `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:uiBusy];` as per @emotality’s answer.

Comment: For the record: You usually want to set `uiBusy.activityIndicatorViewStyle = .gray`

Comment: I use a computed property to access uiBusy: `private var uiBusy: UIActivityIndicatorView {
        if let busyView = self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.customView as? UIActivityIndicatorView {
            return busyView
        } else {
            let uiBusy = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .white)
            uiBusy.hidesWhenStopped = true
            uiBusy.activityIndicatorViewStyle = .gray
            self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: uiBusy)
            return uiBusy
        }
    }`

Answer (score 6):

```
activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];
activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:activityIndicator];
```

Place the following where ever is needed:

```
[activityIndicator startAnimating];
[activityIndicator stopAnimating];
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually activity indicator is not added as toolbar item. It's a subview of current view.

```
    UIActivityIndicatorView *act = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];
    [act setCenter:CGPointMake(20, 20)];
    [act startAnimating];
    [self.view addSubview:act];
```

Remember to release it in `-(void)dealloc`.

Comment: More information about how to use activity indicator is here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/593234/how-to-use-activity-indicator-view-on-iphone

Answer (score 0):

Use this Methods

```
-(void)startAniatingActivityIndicator{
@try {
    activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];
    activityIndicator.frame = CGRectMake(self.window.frame.size.width-30, 32.5, activityIndicator.bounds.size.width, activityIndicator.bounds.size.height);
    [self.window addSubview:activityIndicator];
    [activityIndicator startAnimating];
    [self.window bringSubviewToFront:activityIndicator];
}
@catch (NSException *exception) {

}
@finally {

}
```

}

```
-(void)stopAniatingActivityIndicator{
[activityIndicator stopAnimating];
[activityIndicator removeFromSuperview];
activityIndicator = nil;
```

}

Answer (score -1):

UIActivityIndicatorView is a type of view.  Set its frame to be within your button and use -addSubview to add it to the view hierarchy of the UIBarButton.

I'm oversimplifying, since you have to try to make it fit the space (possibly by scaling) and center it...

Answer (score -2):

pseudocode, i'm not going to check this in Xcode, but something like this should work:

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *act = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] init];
act.frame = CGMakeRect(3,3,25,25);
[myBarButton addSubview:act];
[act release];
```

Comment: `UIBarButtonItem` isn't a `UIView` subclass and doesn't have `addSubview:`. You should do something like `UIBarButtonItem *myBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:act];` instead or `myBarButton.customView = act;`.