# How to make a UIActivityIndicatorView in a UIToolbar tappable

Tags: objective-c, uitoolbar, uiactivityindicatorview

I'm using this code to insert an UIActivityIndicatorView to my toolbar

```
-(void)addActivityIndicatorToToolbar {
    UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20)];
    activityIndicator.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite;
    [activityIndicator startAnimating];

    UIBarButtonItem *barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:activityIndicator];
    barButton.target = self;
    barButton.action = @selector(playButtonPressed:);

    NSMutableArray *toolbarItemsMutable = [self.toolbar.items mutableCopy];
    [toolbarItemsMutable replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:barButton];
    self.toolbar.items = toolbarItemsMutable;  
}
```

However, when I tap the UIActivityIndicatorView the action (playButtonPressed) is not performed.

How can I correct this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up implementing a poor man's solution by adding an extra view on top of the activityIndicatorView with a gestureRecognizer.

Answer (score 1):

It seems more likely that you want a button with an activity indicator inside it. You can do this by creating a button with a custom view as described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1719533/add-uiactivityindicatorview-into-uibarbutton). Then you can set the action of this button as normal, and you'll probably want to retain a reference to the activity indicator to start and stop it.

Comment: I used the storyboard to add the toolbar to my view. It does not have the property rightBarButtonItem...

Comment: On reading your post more clearly I can see you are setting the activity indicator as a custom view inside a button, apologies for misreading. Does the button show the activity indicator and push in when you press it? 

It could be the selector name. Is the method `-(void)playButtonPressed:(id)sender` defined in the same class, or do you have `-(void)playButtonPressed`?

Comment: the button does not push it. i've got  -(void)playButtonPressed:(id)sender defined in the same class (so the colon on the end of the selector is correct) Meanwhile I implemented a poor man's solution by adding an extra view on top of the activityIndicatorView with a gestureRecognizer. A more elegant solution would be nice.

Comment: Try setting `activityIndicator.userInteractionEnabled = NO` instead of `YES`. It could be that the activity indicator is eating the taps.

Answer (score 0):

This is a quite old question but why don't you directly add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` instance to your `UIActivityIndicatorView` instance ? (works fine on iOS 8.2, I didn't test yet on previous versions).