# Change zoomScale and contentOffset of UIScrollView in UIApplicationStateBackground state

Tags: ios, uiview, uiwebview, uiscrollview, uikit

I know it's not recommended to change any view appearance when the application is moved to background state, but for my specific task I cannot postpone this activity and I really like to complete it in a couple of seconds after the user hits the home button.

That's what I do:
**I load a webpage in a UIWebView and after loading completion I change the contentOffset and zoomScale in order to make a specific screenshot of that webpage.** When the app is in active application state everything works fine.

Now I wanted to add some more multitasking capabilities. I encapsulated the above described webpage loading and rendering activity in a **protected background task** (iOS Task Completion), **in order to complete it even when the user hits the home button.**

I have noticed that the page loading and the rendering of the webpage screenshot (with the renderInContext: method) works just fine in background, **BUT it seems that the webview** (i.e. the encapsulated UIScrollView instance) **does not react on setContentOffset: and setZoomScale: messages as soon as the app is in background.**.

So I'm asking you if you know any alternatives to change the content offset / zoomscale? (modifications directly on CALayer?) Or any method to "force" the scrollview to perform the content changes even in background.

PS: On the iOS simulator everything works fine even in application background state, but on real devices it does not.

**EDIT: I have created a simple demo project that demonstrates the issue. You can download it here (please read the instructions in the zip file): http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3556271/BackgroundBugDemo.zip**

I appreciate every hint or tip. Thanks!

Comment: Only use the [tag:objective-c] tag for questions about the language itself. Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8031912/792677

Comment: @ErwaySoftware Sorry!

Comment: @A-Live I think this does not relate to my question. I've checked that  I perform the changes to the webview on the main thread. My problem relates to the fact that the application itself is in background state while performing these changes...

Comment: After consulting Apple DTS, they advised me to open bug report. I've created one (ID 13598083), but I appreciate every workaround to accomplish my desired behavior.

Comment: I have created a simple demo project that demonstrates the issue. You can download it here (please read the instructions in the zip file): https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3556271/BackgroundBugDemo.zip