# adding HUD to UIImageView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiimage, hud

I am pulling an UIImage asynchronously to show it in my UIImageView, while I am waiting for the image, I want to show a spinner/HUD inside the UIImageView. What is a good spinner/HUD to be shown inside a HUD? I've seen a few apps that does this, not sure what to use.

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like [UIActivityIndicatorView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIActivityIndicatorView_Class/Reference/UIActivityIndicatorView.html)?

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593234/how-to-use-activity-indicator-view-on-iphone) which covers various alternatives.