# how to block user , if he/she not connected to internet connection when my app load

Tags: ios, swift, reachability

I have one app, which is fully map view.What I need is I need to show some alert if user not connected to internet . I have done that. Here is the code :

```
Reachability.swift.

import Foundation
import SystemConfiguration

public class Reachability {

    class func isConnectedToNetwork() -> Bool {

        var zeroAddress = sockaddr_in(sin_len: 0, sin_family: 0, sin_port: 0, sin_addr: in_addr(s_addr: 0), sin_zero: (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
        zeroAddress.sin_len = UInt8(sizeofValue(zeroAddress))
        zeroAddress.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)

        let defaultRouteReachability = withUnsafePointer(&zeroAddress) {
            SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(kCFAllocatorDefault, UnsafePointer($0))
        }

        var flags: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags = SCNetworkReachabilityFlags(rawValue: 0)
        if SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(defaultRouteReachability!, &flags) == false {
             return false
        }

        let isReachable = flags == .Reachable
        let needsConnection = flags == .ConnectionRequired

        return isReachable && !needsConnection

    }
}
if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork() == true {
    println("Internet connection OK")
} else {
    println("Internet connection FAILED")
    var alert = UIAlertView(title: "No Internet Connection", message: "Make sure your device is connected to the internet.", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
    alert.show()
}
```

But what I need is : when user not connected to internet , one `UIAlertView` message will show. in that alert I have one `OK` button. So till user connect to internet , it is possible to redirect them to mobile data on/off settings or it is possible to show `UIAlertView` message till the user connect to internet..

Please help me out !!

Comment: If I were a user of your app, I wouldn't care if I am connected or not when the app starts -- unless, I will need to access remote services. So, in your app, just try to connect _when_ it is requested, and when it fails due to unreachable server, let the user know.

Answer (score 0):

On click of ok button in alertview you can redirect the user to desired page, calling the appropriate segue. second option if you want to block the user, just show an activity indicator with the custom message.

Comment: Thats what i am asking , how to show uialert continuously , till user connect to internet ???

Comment: You should not go for continuously showing UIAlertview, instead show the user UIActivityIndicator. which in itself shows that some process is going on. check the following for ActivityIndicator :

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/593234/how-to-use-activity-indicator-view-on-iphone

Comment: ok, then where i have to add this uiactivityIndicator... And how i know again user connect the internet . so stop the uiactivity indicator

Comment: inside my else statement ??

Comment: That depends on your code logic. On high level : Just start showing activity indicator wherever you want, when your phone gets connected call a method and write the code to remove the activity indicator in this method. Hope it would help.

Answer (score 0):

One thing is letting users know about the network status.

Having your app built to support all of these network states is completely different thing.

Make sure your users are aware of the current network status but also make sure your application behaves accordingly to it.

And no, you cannot redirect directly to Wi-Fi Settings.

Comment: Then, how to show uialert continuously , till user connect to internet ???, please give me some code explain

Comment: Depends on what continuously means for you. If you stick to the guidelines provided by Apple, your application should notify the user about the network status when there is an action performed by them that requires network access. Like refreshing the feed for example. I cannot give you a complete code example because your question is too abstract. A good option would be to show an alert view every time you try to reach server, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Launch iOS Device Settings page

**Step.1** Go to Project settings --> Info --> URL Types --> Add New URL Schemes

[image]

**Step.2** Check for internet in viewWillAppear method and show the alert

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool)
    {
        //check for internet
        if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork() == true
        {
            print("Internet connection OK")

        }
        else
        {
            print("Internet connection off")

            let alertView: UIAlertView = UIAlertView(title: "Alert!", message: "Please enable internet settings", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "Settings", otherButtonTitles: "Cancel")
            alertView.show()
            return
        }
    }
```

**Step.3** Handle alert button click

```
func alertView(alertView: UIAlertView, clickedButtonAtIndex buttonIndex: Int)
    {
        if buttonIndex == 0
        {
                //This will open ios devices wifi settings
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "prefs:root")!)
        }
        else if buttonIndex == 1
        {
            //TODO for cancel
        }
    }
```

*Note:* Do not forget to confirm `UIAlertViewDelegate`

---

See here **full example code** I have tested

```
import UIKit


class ViewController: UIViewController, UIAlertViewDelegate
{

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }


    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool)
    {
        //check for internet
        if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork() == true
        {
            print("Internet connection OK")
        }
        else
        {
            print("Internet connection off")

            let alertView: UIAlertView = UIAlertView(title: "Alert!", message: "Please enable internet settings", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "Settings", otherButtonTitles: "Cancel")
            alertView.show()
            return
        }
    }



    func alertView(alertView: UIAlertView, clickedButtonAtIndex buttonIndex: Int)
    {
        if buttonIndex == 0
        {
                //This will open ios devices wifi settings
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "prefs:root")!)
        }
        else if buttonIndex == 1
        {
            //TODO for cancel
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

Comment: Actually, what your code does??, its just an uialert to show one time or till user connect to internet it will show uialert continuously ??

Comment: I added the answer as you asked, see your comment to @damirstuhec answer, let me update my answer for redirecting user to iphone setting as per network availability.

Comment: in view did load i add your first section code. And i add that func method.But its not redirecting and show as usual uialert message

Answer (score 0):

1-) Your App Target > Info > URL Types then add new URL Types like this;

[image]

2-) In your AppDelegate, define this variable;

```
var isInternetConnected = false
```

3-) In your `UIViewController`, define an AppDelegate variable then in `UIViewController viewDidLoad()` method, start listening connection;

```
let appDelegate: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "internetNotifier:", name: kReachabilityChangedNotification, object: nil)
    Reachability.reachabilityForInternetConnection().startNotifier()
}
```

4-) In your internetNotifier method, check connection;

```
func internetNotifier(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let reachObject = notification.object as? Reachability {
        switch reachObject.isReachable() {
        case true:
            appDelegate.isInternetConnected = true
            hideAlertController()
        case false:
            appDelegate.isInternetConnected = false
            presentViewController(UIAlertController.showAlertController(), animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}

func hideAlertController() {
    if self.navigationController?.visibleViewController is UIAlertController {
         dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

5-) Create new Extension of `UIAlertController` in your `AppDelegate`;

```
extension UIAlertController {

    class final func showAlertController() -> UIAlertController {
        let internetController = self.init(title: "Error", message: "No internet connection. Go to Settings and open your Wi-Fİ", preferredStyle: .Alert)
        internetController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Go to Settings", style: .Default, handler: { (internetController) -> Void in
            if let settingsURL = NSURL(string: "prefs:root=WIFI") where UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(settingsURL) {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(settingsURL)
                }
            }
        }))
        return internetController
    }

}
```

6-) Last and the most important step is, call your `UIAlertController` in AppDelegate;

```
func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
    if !isInternetConnected {
       window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(UIAlertController.showAlertController(), animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Because, if user go settings open network then back your application and still not connection, you need to show him your alert again. Do not forget remove your connection observer in your `UIViewController`;

```
deinit {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: kReachabilityChangedNotification, object: nil)
    Reachability.reachabilityForInternetConnection().stopNotifier()
}
```